# Does the singularity require maintenance?

Tags: space-station-13

After a few rounds as engineer I'm pretty comfortable with getting the singularity engine up and running.

During a few of the rounds however, the singularity got loose and destroyed parts of the station. Does it require any maintenance once it's up and running, or did someone just sabotage it when things went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not it is sabatoge, which is remarkably easy to do to the singularity.  Even so, this alone is a reason you or another engineer should regularly check on it to make sure it's okay.

There's quite a few things that can go wrong.

- Plasma tanks could be low, in whichc case you'll need to replace them with new tanks, which you should be able to check with your PDA
- Shields could be lowered, either by accident or by sabatoge
- Emitter could be broken, either by accident or sabatoge
- Emission rate could be set too high (it should be on, but always set to 0)
- Containment could be compromised, usually by sabatoge but occasionally accidents can happen
- The darn thing could just grow too big

The last point is one you'll be wanting to check on about every 15 minutes or so. If it gets to a 4x4 size, then it has gotten too big and is in danger of breaking out of containment.  You'll want to turn the emitter off until it returns to a size of 3x3.

Comment: How can I see if the plasma thanks are too low or not? Could you edit that into your answer?

Comment: I believe your PDA should be able to check the pressure on a tank.  You have to enable the function and click on the tank itself.  I don't believe there's any way to check without taking the tank out, unfortunately.